# MVC C# Handling error in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need a way to handle exceptions globally, in a way that a message(for example popup message) is shown in the same view that the error was thrown in ( That is without redirecting to an separate error view)
something like:
[image]

I am using MVC5 with C#

Comment: if exception is thrown in view - this view is dead and can't be returned

Comment: "could not collect the puzzle pieces together!" is not a very concrete question. And asking for a repeat of that entire project/blog is too broad.

Comment: @bommelding I meant that I read the different ways, but couldn't know which t use

Comment: Well, neither can I.

Comment: Have you read [ask]? Have you read [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, and I dont have code to give, since I am unable to find how to write such code, and this is the problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: @PlexisPlexis - But you said "I tried some code found over the internet". You do seem to have code. Also the [ask] page tells you how to ask. Does your question fit the same quality standards mentioned there?

Comment: @Enigmativity check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c?rq=1
is this a quality question with verifiable code? it has a score of 1741 upvotes and 391 bookmarks!

Comment: @bommelding I didn't mention the blog for you to read it all! I mentioned it as the "Standards" ask us to show what we have done, or to provide our "Search efforts"!

Comment: @PlexisPlexis - Really? Are you saying that your question is as clearly written as that one?

Comment: @Enigmativity No, may be it is not clear, my point is that lot of questions do not obey the standards and the guidelines u sent, and receive tons of upvotings!

Comment: @PlexisPlexis - Sure, and lots of people break laws so maybe those laws should be scrapped? I showed you the pages published by this site to help improve the quality of the questions. That's all.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, I know, and thanks for that, but sometimes, it is bad to feel unsupported! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way to have a global exception handler and keep on the same page.

The global.asax is the place where you do global error handling in Asp.Net, if you want to remain on the page just use try/catch in the Controller.

Tip: Sometimes when an exception occurs, it's too late at the global exception handler as the stack has unwound and you can't even see which page/function/parameters caused the error. Unless you get a memory dump. This behaviour applies to Winform, WPF, Asp.Net...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using a custom approach.
What I did is that I added try-catch for the methods I need to handle.

And in the catch block I set a `ViewBag.ErrorMessage` to the message exception, and then return the view of the action method (for example, Create, Edit) and in the view I retrieve the `ViewBag.ErrorMessage` and show it.

Comment: Nice one! Make sure you log those errors and 
get the logs sent to you  :)

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you! yes I need to add a log