# Birthday calculator no value after timespan

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a small birthday (years) calculator, and somehow the value after the timespan disappears.

I've tried converting to DateTime and then to double but still no effect.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine("Type your birthday: ");
DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
TimeSpan age = (today - b);
string s = age.ToString();
double final = double.Parse(s) / 365.2425;

Console.WriteLine("You have" + final + "years");
```

Comment: Have a look here for several solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "and somehow the value after the timespan disappears."? What result did you get vs what you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `age.Days`. `age.ToString()` will return you something like `dddd.00:00:00` where `dddd` are days. But you only need days, so `age.Days` will do the job.

But I suggest that you use `age.TotalDays` because it returns a `double` so you don't have to parse it. Complete snippet:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine("Type your birthday: ");
DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

TimeSpan age = (today - b);
double final = age.TotalDays / 365.2425;

Console.WriteLine("You have" + final + "years");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the result of `age.ToString()` you will see a value like `10265.00:00:00` which cant be correctly parsed as double.

Use the `.Days` property of the `TimeSpan` class, and you can omit the parsing altogether.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine("Type your birthday: ");
DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
TimeSpan age = (today - b);
double final = age.Days / 365.2425;

Console.WriteLine("You have" + final + "years");
```