# How can i make this program calculate my age correctly? (probably simple, I'm a beginner)

Tags: c#

I'm writing a small console program that calculates your age and I will add some other things later, but the problem is that this code does not calculates the age properly, it just substracts actualYear - birthYear, but if you did not had your birthday yet it displays a wrong age, how can I make this sum all the days and months that i have? I tried a lot of things and didn't work :(

Is there any way to do this using an if statement?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace para_joel
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public string surname;

        public int birthDay;
        public int birthMonth;
        public int birthYear;

        public int Age()
        {
            int actualYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int actualMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
            int actualDay = DateTime.Now.Day;

            return actualYear - birthYear;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet that if you open this question on a computer (not a phone), one of the suggestions on the right side has to do with calculating an age with C#. Google and/or Bing will get you there too

Comment: One of the 63 answers should help you

Comment: Those don't really solve their problem though. Their issue is that they're storing the birthday as three separate numbers. They need to first convert those into a DateTime and then follow the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert your three int properties from Person into a Datetime with something like this:

```
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
```

Then you need to convert today's date into a datetime (not how i'd do it, but using your variables):

```
DateTime today = new DateTime(actualYear, actualMonth, actualDay);
```

Then you need to subtract the two:

```
var age = today - birthday;
```

this will return days, so you'll want to divide by 365 to get years in age and you can do rounding as needed once you get that far.