# Can calculate age with user input in C#, but don't know why it works

Tags: c#, calculator

So I used a solution found on a question from a different user here, link: [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c), where the DOB was hardcoded, I added the code to take in a user input from the console to then calculate the age, however I don't know why the if statement produces a correct result, without it, it calculates the age you'll be that year, not your actual age.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine("Type in your D.O.B in DD-MM-YYYY format:");
var Bday = Console.ReadLine();
var myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Bday);
var age = today.Year - myDate.Year;
if (myDate.Date > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
Console.WriteLine($"You are {age} years old");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking about how this line works:

```
if (myDate.Date > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
```

The number of years has been calculated by subtracting the year from the *DOB* from the year *now*.  For example, if your DOB was 15/05/1979 and now is 2020 this would give:

```
age = 2020 - 1979 = 41
```

However, if this person's DOB was after today, they would not be 41 *yet*, they would still be 40.

In the case of the `if` statement, if the *date* of their birth (the month and day) is after today, one year is subtracted from `age` to give the correct age (which would be 40 in my example).

The logic is not as concise as it could be, but essentially it says:

- Take the calculated age in years from today's date (example: 15/05/1979 = 41 years, 12/01/2020 - 41 years = 12/01/1979)
- Is the DOB *after* this value? (is 15/05/1979 AFTER 12/01/1979)
- If yes, subtract 1 from age (example: 41 - 1 = 40 years)

Comment: I think you mean "if the date of their birth (the month and day)".

Comment: @juharr I did mean that, thank you. Will correct it now

Comment: One important thing about doing exactly like that (subtracting age from current year), instead of doing simpler comparison like: "if (bday.AddYears(age) > now) age--;" is that it would circumvent leap year problem. There's a comment by Mike Polen in the initial discussion regarding this.