# make one date bigger than other c#

Tags: c#, date

Hello so I have this condition:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dateTimePicker_Doc_BirthDate.Value).Days/(365)<18)
{
    this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.dateTimePicker_Doc_BirthDate, "Atleast 18 years old");
    valid = false;
}
```

And I want to make another that contains graduation of this person and set restriction that at the time when he graduat must be *atleast* `18` years older.

I have tried this: but *it does not work*

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dateTimePicker_Doc_Graduation.Value).Days / (365) < 18 + (18))
{
    this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.dateTimePicker_Doc_Graduation, "Atleast 18");
    valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Side note: It's a problem with *leap years*. When a person born in `29 Feb 2004` will be `18` years old? `1 Mar 2022` or `28 Feb 2022`?

Comment: `29 Feb 2076`? :D

Comment: Years aren't uniformly 365 days long. If you want to ensure that they're 18 years old, better to subtract 18 years from today's date and ensure that the DOB is earlier. I'm not sure what you're wanting to check with the graduation date, you've not explained very well what the requirement is.

Comment: DateTime from = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            var yearold = Math.Round((now - from).TotalDays / 356);

Comment: "Graduation is the successful completion of a course of study at a university, college, or school, for which you receive a degree or diploma".  So the term "graduation date" is unclear by it's meaning.

Comment: @PhatHuynh leap years. Different calendars. This doesn't work

Comment: At the very least, you should use [Calendar.AddYears](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.addyears?view=netframework-4.8). The `DateTime` type *doesn't* have `AddYears` or even `AddMonths` on purpose. There are leap years to consider and different countries can sue different calendars

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, That's a trick question.. It depends of the legislation computing the age. Not only the country, for example New zealand use 28 for driver license and 1rst for everything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is *leap year*. When a person born in `29 Feb 2004` will be `18` year old? There are *two* possible answers:

https://www.buzzfeed.com/lanesainty/leap-year-birthday-teenager-court-ruling

1. `28 Feb 2022` (New Zealand for driving license; see xdtTransform's comment)
2. `1 Mar 2022` (Australia)

In a simple case, we can just add `18` year to the `birthDate` and see if 18th birth day is before or after `today`. For `29 February` we may well have to add `1 day` as well:

```
 DateTime birthDate = dateTimePicker_Doc_BirthDate.Value.Date;
 DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
 // 0 for 28 Feb 2022; 1 for 1 Mar 2022 
 int leapPolicy = 1;

 if (birthDate.AddYears(18) <= today || // 18th birthday before today or today
     birthDate.Day == 29 &&   
     birthDate.Day == 2 && 
     birthDate.AddYears(18).AddDays(leapPolicy) == today) {

   // At least 18 years old
 }
```

Please, note, that year is *not* `365` but `365.2425` days ([Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)) that's why you can't put it as `...Days / 365...`