# How do I extract a chunk of text from a text file?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have a postscript file that has a starting indicator of where I want to begin copying data to a StringBuilder that reads:

```
$$StartCopy
$$ChunkID[1234]
$$Type[Foo]
\\bla bla for hundreds or thousands of lines
$$EndCopy  

$$StartCopy
$$ChunkID[4567]
$$Type[Bar]
\\bla bla for hundreds or thousands of lines
$$EndCopy 


$$StartCopy
$$ChunkID[4567]
$$Type[Foo]
\\bla bla for hundreds or thousands of lines
$$EndCopy

$$StartCopy
$$ChunkID[8901]
$$Type[Bar]
\\bla bla for hundreds or thousands of lines
$$EndCopy
```

Note that there is no specific line that I can start at, nor is there any set number of lines between $$StartCopy and $$EndCopy. In this case, how do I grab the chunk of text `$$Chunk[4567]` where `$$Type[Bar]` from its start to end line?

To be clear, here is what the end result should be:

```
$$StartCopy
$$ChunkID[4567]
$$Type[Bar]
\\bla bla for hundreds or thousands of lines
$$EndCopy
```

Comment: What does this mean exactly "*In this case, how do I grab the chunk of text $$Chunk[4567] where $$Type[Bar] from its start to end line*" its not very specific and kind of a bit muddled. whats an end line?. Show the **exact** output you want

Comment: BTW, despite making comment it is not @MichaelRandall who downvoted the post for lack of demonstrated research... Showing where you are stuck would make answering much easier than explaining how to read strings from file, compare strings for equality, deal with Boolean and string variables, concatenating strings, basic loops and `break;` statement...

Comment: @MichaelRandall the End Line is `$$EndCopy`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov much like the author of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

I am also looking for best practice, and a clean solution. I doubt the poster was someone who was new to C# the same in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a large file and lots of results, it's probably better to use [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8) which returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and an [iterator method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators)

```
/// <summary>
/// Will return the data from a file between the start and end parameters (inclusive)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">duh</param>
/// <param name="start">The start of the sequence</param>
/// <param name="end">The end of the sequence</param>
/// <returns>Stuff</returns>
public static IEnumerable<string> GetData(string fileName, string start, string end)
{
   var found = false;
   foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
   {
      if (line == start) found = true;

      if (!found) continue;

      yield return line;

      if (line == end) break;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = GetData(fileName, "$$StartCopy", "$$EndCopy");
```

<sub>***Note*** : This code is completely untested and void of any warranty claims, take backs, or returns due to the people you may harm or otherwise maim with this code</sub>

**Great comment by [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)**

> The problem with *NET's* built-in `ReadLine`/`ReadLineAsync`/`ReadLines`
>   methods is that they use the `Environment.NewLine` string and doesn't
>   let you manually specify a *line-terminator*, making them useless for
>   writing *cross-platform code*

Which is to say, this method really only deals with the following situations because of the inherent use of [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netframework-4.8) when determining what an actual *line* is.

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Comment: The problem with NET's built-in `ReadLine`/`ReadLineAsync`/`ReadLines` methods is that they use the `Environment.NewLine` string and don't let you manually specify a line-terminator, making them useless for writing cross-platform code.

Comment: @Dai its worthy of a note, as people have their fingers in also sorts of platforms these days

Comment: Does it? [StreamReader.ReadLine()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,731). `File.ReadLines()` just creates the Iterator, which of course calls `StreamReader.ReadLine()`.