# How to calculate age by input field date on the frontend?

Tags: c#, blazor, data-annotations, blazor-webassembly

I have a model which has a field called

```
public DateTime birthday {get ; set; } = DateTime.Today;
public int age = 0;
```

My Razor file

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
     <InputDate class="input100" id="birthday" @bind-value="CurrentCustomerModel.birthday" />
</div>
```

so what I am trying to do is some front end validation. If the person is less than 50 years old, I want to display a message saying "Sorry you are too young" (or anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Age` should not be stored data - it's a calculated value based on the time of the query; therefore I would recommend making it a read-only property that's calculated on the fly:

```
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

public int Age
{
    get
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var age = today.Year - Birthday.Year;
        if (Birthday.Date > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
        return age;
    }
}
```

Now you have a calculated field that will give the accurate `Age` (in years), which you can then use to compare against `50`.

Note that the age calculation comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/in-c-how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-based-on-a-datetime-type-birthday).

Comment: I lost you at the if statement.

Comment: It's not enough to subtract the year, so that line checks the actual date. For example if you were born in October but it's only September, then you haven't had a birthday yet so we subtract `1` from the age.