# What is a command equivalent to DateTime?

Tags: shell, datetime

I learned shell scripting for a little while and decided to recreate [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/) accepted answer, though I can't really find how a `DateTime` equivalent would be in it.

How can I get a `DateTime` command? (In relation to [Date time in Linux bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85982/date-time-in-linux-bash))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date by passing the `date` argument when declaring a variable:

```
var=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
```

And as pointed out by **[@Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus)**, you can also not use `date` via:

```
printf -v var "%(%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)T\n" -1
```

Comment: Or with `bash` >= version 4.2: `printf -v var "%(%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)T\n" -1`