# Asp.net gridview Sorting by age

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a table with column "Age", where sorted age is shown like:

```
10 years,
105 years
18 years,
60 years.
8 months.
```

How can I sort it not in alphabetical order, but in correct.
I can't eliminate word "years".

Comment: this is how you have saved it on database ? if yes, then you have to redesign the table with one more field with the actually time in datetime format (or in ticks)

Comment: Can you put the code of gridview data bind?

Comment: no, in database is stored birthdate, the age is calculated, as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if this is from say a database?

Then  you could do this:

```
SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Age, 
  cast(SUBSTRING(Age,1,Charindex(' ',Age)-1 ) as integer) as NumAge
  FROM tblCustomers
  ORDER BY NumAge
```

So, now you have a text display column, but you also have a real "number" column with the actual number in years - and you can sort correctly on that NumAge column. And this sort could also be done with a data-view sort - so however you were/are sorting the data, then sorting by NumAge will become a possible choice if you add the above column that plucks out the number from that column.

Now the Above works if we don't have a mix of month, and years. But, to handle that, then we change above to this:

```
SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Age, 
    CASE
      WHEN CharIndex('month',Age) > 0 THEN
        (cast(SUBSTRING(Age,1,Charindex(' ',Age)-1 ) as integer))
      WHEN CharIndex('year',Age) > 0 THEN
        (cast(SUBSTRING(Age,1,Charindex(' ',Age)-1 ) * 12 as integer))
    END 
     AS AgeInMonths
  FROM tblCustomers
  ORDER BY AgeInMonths
```

So, once again, we now have a number and value in months for age, and this can be sorted. So we display the Age + text column, but the sort expression can use AgeInMonths and the result is data in the correct order.

And if you have days? Then I would in place of the months * 12, using months * 30, and for year, then just use * 365. So, it not at all hard to have support for years, months, or days.

The result is once again, data sorted in number order by given age.

Comment: How can I show 15 years, but store ans sort like "15"?

Comment: Quite much thought I just explained how. You simply continue to display your text column, but when you sort, you sort on the new column. So you now have two columns - your existing one for display with age + text, but you now simply sort based on this now available number column.  So your sort or order by expression will work against NumAge. However, the months example column is a issue - I'll update my post to handle that issue.

Comment: See my edit to the above post - I added support for years, and months.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is also "months". Is 8 months higher than 2 years or is 8 months 0 year?
If it is the last you can use `Linq`.
Lets say this are the ages.

```
var age = new List<string>()
{
    "10 years,",
    "105 years",
    "18 years,",
    "60 years.",
    "8 months.",
    "1 year.",
    "18 months,",
 };
```

Then you can do this. It splits the list in months and years. Then removes all characters except numbers. If it is a month divide it by 12 to get the years. Then sort it, and make it a string again and add "years" to it.

```
var sortedAge = age.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains("month"))
   .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(string.Concat(x.Where(Char.IsDigit))) / 12)
   .Concat(age.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains("year"))
   .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(string.Concat(x.Where(Char.IsDigit)))))
   .OrderBy(y => y)
   .Select(z => z > 1 ? z.ToString() + " years" : z.ToString() + " year").ToList();
```

result

```
0 year
1 year
1 year
10 years
18 years
60 years
105 years
```

But you would still be better off just storing the age as an int in the DOB or even better, the date of birth as datetime.

Comment: so, if I store birthdate, how can I show age and sort by it?

Comment: If you store brthdate you can simply calculate the age: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-based-on-a-datetime-type-birthday

Comment: It is a heck of a lot easier to scale up the numbers then trying to divide them down. Just assume everything is in months - and the whole problem becomes easy. One will continue to display the age + text, but you simply sort on a column that represents the months. (see my post above). However, it not at all clear why the DOB, or some number value was never stored/saved in the first place. But, see my post - I show a rather easy T-SQL means of converting the given text into a number of months value , and then one can sort on that AgeInMonths, but continue to display the age + text.

Comment: If you have the option to save DOB, then it will automatic always sort by number value. You use a date, or datetime column for this. This allows you to display the DOB format anyway you want, including things like You are 2 years, 5 months and 3 days old. So without question go with a date/datetime column, since how you display that column does not effect that sorting by DOB - it will always automatic and always sort by correct order. and you can use Month(DOB) to get the current month, so a query to show who has a birthday this month is also trivial.