# What is wrong with my implementation of this method to calculate a person's age?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate age using [the method suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942/73226),

> format the date to yyyymmdd and subtract the date of birth (also yyyymmdd) from the
> current date then drop the last 4 digits you've got the age

I tried this.

```
((CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(30),  GETDATE()  , 112)  AS INT))-CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(30),  @date, 112)  AS INT)/100000)
```

But it returns me the same number 20210428

Comment: Why are you dividing dates in the first place?

Comment: If you're expecting a decimal result you need to do /100000.0, this will convert the result to decimal as it has higher order of precedence. Why however is a mystery!

Comment: It's not a mystery at all, @Stu . An expression made up of `int`s is going to return a `int`.

Comment: @Larnu lol Yeah I meant why subtracting and dividing the dates, not the division :)

Comment: You appear to be unaware of the `DATEDIFF` function, which can calculate differences without the need for these rather dubious casting practices. Even for advanced scenarios where you have to do more intricate calculations there's generally no need for using layers of conversions; see `DATEADD`, `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`.

Comment: What is the purpose of this query?

Comment: @Larnu I want to calculate age using the method where you substract dates, e.g. now is 20210428, a person was born in 19990901, so his age is (20210428 -  19990901) = 21

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah, I am aware of it, it just won't work for my work

Comment: That would be `DATEDIFF(MONTH, @date, GETDATE()) / 12`, or `12.0` and round up or down as required. `DATEDIFF` counts intervals crossed, not absolute difference, so a useful trick/guideline is to go down one level of granularity.

Comment: Does SQL Server not have an [interval type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)?

Comment: @Schwern thank yoy for your help, but I just want to stick to my method (weird but working) it is actually widely used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but there's some precedence problems and you're dividing by too much.

Let's add some whitespace, the final frontier.

```
declare @date datetime = '1999-04-29';

select (
  (CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(30),  GETDATE()  , 112)  AS INT)) - 
  CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(30),  @date, 112)  AS INT) / 100000
);
```

Because / has a higher precedence than -, it's 20200428 - 19. Once that's fixed we see that 1000000 is too much. 100,000 is 10^5 so it will remove 5 digits. If you want to remove 4 digits (2 for the month and 2 for the day) you want to integer divide by 10^4 or 10,000.

```
select (
  CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)  AS INT) - 
  CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @date, 112)  AS INT)
) / 10000;
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86353dc8fb294f58f6ec5bb4b1805f18).