# Calculate age in view C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have calculate age in view using something like this...

For example I have this in view:

```
 <dt>
     Age
 </dt>
 <dd>
     @(DateTime.Now - this.Model.dateofbirth)
 </dd>
```

but the result shows it to me in days, I want age in years. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate someone's age based on a DateTime type birthday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-based-on-a-datetime-type-birthday)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@(DateTime.Now - this.Model.dateofbirth).Year
```

Because both variables are Datetimes the subtract result will be `Datetime` which has a `Year` property.