# TimeSpan between UTC and AUS local

Tags: c#, timespan, timezone-offset

I don't understand the result of the following code:

```
request.Dob = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Parse("24-03-1961"));
TimeSpan ts = request.Dob - DateTime.Parse("24-03-1961");
```

I am in AEDT time zone (Sydney) so the time span (between UTC and local) I reckon should be -10 hours, but time span shows me -11 hours. I am so confused - where is that 1 hour difference coming from?

Comment: I have no idea what Australia is :) but I'm pretty sure its government claims multiple timezones all with DST - https://www.australia.gov.au/time-zones-and-daylight-saving... Please make sure to [edit] your post with the *exact name of the timezone* along with the exact date that causing your "problem".

Comment: `(DateTime)worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value` <-- There's a potential bug here: a `DateTime` value **might** have `Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc` or `.Local` or `.Unspecified` - and each of those options will affect the end calculation. You should first get the cell value, then assert the `.Kind`, _then_ convert to UTC.

Comment: It looks like you are East Coast, There is AEST and AEDT. Brisbane is AEST while Sydney for example is AEDT. For winter months both are +10, but in summer months AEDT is +11. So if you're in Brisbane, check that your machine/server isn't accidentally set to AEDT (Sydney etc.) That, or you forgot about daylight savings kicking over last week  :)

Comment: Rather than using `DateTime.Parse` with a literal, just use the `int year, int month, int day` ctor - and always prefer using `ParseExact` with an explicit `IFormatProvider` - finally, no-one uses `dd-MM-yyyy` as a format, Australia uses `dd/MM/yyyy` - but we should _all_ be using RFC 3339 (`yyyy-MM-dd`) instead to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I have updated my question to Alexei Levenkov suggestions.

Comment: It was indeed DST problem. I thought though that the system would adjust it automatically and i don't have to do any adjustments in my code.

Comment: @janci - I presume "dob" is "date of birth".  If so - you should _not_ be converting between local/UTC at all.  A birthday refers to a whole date, not a specific time on the date. (Calendars don't have time zones.)  Also, it's unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish on the second line.  Are you trying to calculate someone's age?  if so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404/634824

Comment: @Matt Johnson-Pint I have refactored my code now so I don't convert date/time anymore. I was doing this conversion because the date/time from angular client coming to c# controller was always changed by the time zone. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @janci - Keep in mind that the `Date` object in JavaScript is actually a _timestamp_, not a whole date.  It's poorly named, and has lots of other issues.  Hopefully you've refactored your code to send only the actual selected date from your Angular app.  In other words, send `"1961-03-24"` (in year-month-day format).  Don't send `"1961-03-24T00:00:00.000Z"`.